Issue with OpenAPI documentation generation using .NET 9
I tried to use .NET 9, OpenAPI but I found an issue.
I have these model classes:
public class OrderResponse
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction>? Transactions { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

I created a method in the controller that responds with an OrderResponse. I use OpenApi and Scalar.AspNetCore for Doc UI.
Code is compiled, but when I try to validate the json file with https://editor.swagger.io/, I get this error:

Semantic error at components.schemas.OrderResponse.properties.items.items.$ref
$ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs

When I check the OpenApi file, I see this strange reference in items:
{
    "items":  
    {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
                     "$ref": "#/components/schemas/#/properties/transactions/items/properties/items/items"
                 }
    }
}

UI is looking good but I cannot use this json to generate client using nswag.
Any idea if it's a bug in OpenAPI or I did something wrong?

Can you please add a full [mre]?

I can reproduce it with a Minimal API. See Gist

Related to https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/58915
